# Should I write multiple @return tags in javadoc

Tags: java, return, javadoc, code-documentation

Say I have a java method that returns an array of strings. Inside the method, I have more than one return statements, depending on conditions.

```
public String[] userLogIn() {
    String[] success = {"You", "are", "the", "king"};
    String[] errorMsg = {"You", "are", "nothing"};
    double ran = Math.random();
    if(ran < 0.33)
        return success;
    else if (ran < 0.66)
        return errorMsg;
    else
        return null;
}
```

This example might be too naive. But my point is, should/can I use multiple @return tags, like 
`@return this array if condition 1 is met
 @return that array if condition 2 is met
 @return null if condition 3 is met`
?

I often write one single `@return the login message` but think this makes less sense when there is a null return.
Which way is a better coding practice in general?

Comment: A method can return only one value of a given type (in your case **String[]**), so I would write one **@return** tag and describe the different possible return values.

Comment: I've never seen multiple `@return` tags. Does it render properly in the output (or does it for example only show the last one)?

Comment: What happened when you tried? Did it work as you expected? I'd be surprised if it did.

Comment: @Thilo It only renders the first one

Comment: It only renders the first `@return`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can only have a single `@return` tag in a Javadoc comment. Javadoc is written for the person using your method. It should describe *what* the method does, not *how* it does it. The number of `return` statements in the method is compeletely irrelevant to the documentation reader, the only relevant thing is what your method returns for what inputs.

In your case, you could for example document your example method as follows:

```
/** 
 * Logs in the user.
 *
 * @return the result of the operation if the logging in is successful, or
 *         an error message describing the failure if it is not
 */
public String[] userLogIn() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only have one `@return` tag in valid Javadoc, and the convention [as done by parts of the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) has been to describe what it returns in that single line.

For your case, you would specify all three conditions.